# Creating graph of determined edges and nodes

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I want to create a graph that shows connected nodes and edges. I have determined the nodes and edges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
%matplotlib notebook

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node(y[i]==1, color="blue", size=500)
G.add_node(y[i]==0, color="green", size=300)
G.add_edge(d[k,i]*w[k,i], color="green")
G.add_edge(d[i,j]*f[i,j]>0, color="blue")

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Here are the nodes and edges that are determined ( W[k,i] is a longer list) W & F are edges, Y are nodes. d[i,j] is the distance. Distance is between nodes with given positions.

```
Y[0] 1
Y[1] 1
Y[3] 1
Y[12] 1
Y[57] 1
Y[59] 1
W[22,0] 1
W[23,0] 1
W[24,0] 1
F[0,0] 5
F[0,1] 5
F[1,3] 4
F[3,59] 3
F[3,98] 3.63798e-12
F[8,51] 5.65326e-12
F[24,8] 4.65317e-12
F[25,0] 7.10543e-15
F[25,24] 1.81366e-12
F[51,8] 1.56776e-15
F[51,59] 4.78817e-12
F[57,12] 1
F[59,57] 2
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-314-9036a4e704aa> in <module>
     23 G.add_node(y[i]==1, color="blue", size=500)
     24 G.add_node(y[i]==0, color="green", size=300)
---> 25 G.add_edge(d[k,i]*w[k,i], color="green")
     26 G.add_edge(d[i,j]*f[i,j]>0, color="blue")
     27 

TypeError: add_edge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v_of_edge'
```

What do I need to add to make the graph?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where is the dictionary `y`?

Comment: So y is a binary variable (and w and f as well): 

`N= range(0, nodes)` 

`y = {} # Yi, denoting if a facility is located at site i
for i in N:
        y[i] = MultiModel.addVar (lb = 0, 
                            vtype = GRB.BINARY, 
                            obj = instcost, 
                            name = 'Y[' + str(i) + ']')`

 I don't believe I have a dictionary for `y`

Comment: So in short: I want to make a graph of the list given above. All Y values represent a node, all F values represent edges between the Y nodes and all W values are edges that connect a node k to a Y node.

Answer (score 0):

[add_edge](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html) takes 2 mandatory parameters as an input: `u_of_edge` and `v_of_edge`.
In your code

```
G.add_edge(u_of_edge=d[k,i]*w[k,i], color="green")
             ^^^^^^
G.add_edge(u_of_edge=d[i,j]*f[i,j]>0, color="blue")
             ^^^^^^
```

you are missing the `v_of_edge` node, and that's why you are getting the `TypeError`.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this node? (thanks for your answer)

Comment: it is not clear what `d`, `w`,and `f` are. Show some example of their content and it would be much easier to address the issue. However, if you know your edges and nodes, you just have to pass the 2 endpoints as parameters.